# Autoincrement with MongoEngine

Tags: python, mongodb, mongoengine

I'm developing a blog engine with Flask and MongoEngine, and I need sequential IDs for my posts.

I need MongoEngine to create a new ID for each new post, so I was thinking of doing something like this:

```
class Post(Document):
  title = StringField(required=True)
  content = StringField(required=True)
  published_at = datetime.utcnow()
  id = Post.objects.count() + 1
```

Will this work? is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Firstly, you need to understand why you need incremental id's?  What do they solve?

Theres no native solution in mongoDB - please read: http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/How+to+Make+an+Auto+Incrementing+Field

As you already have a unique identifier with the `pk` of the Post, why not use that?

Finally, if I haven't dissuaded you from folly, there is a [`SequenceField`](https://docs.mongoengine.org/apireference.html#mongoengine.fields.SequenceField) in mongoengine that handles incrementing for you.

Comment: I want incremental IDs for posts, as well as users, the auto-generated ids aren't suitable for use in URLs, that's why I want to create my own.

Comment: Sure but you could make human readable slugs - that way it will also improve the accessibility of the urls as well.

Comment: `SequenceField` is the only and best implementation for Autoincrement in Mongoengine.

Answer (score 2):

**Edit**: This is an incorrect solution, as others pointed out that this approach causes a race condition. I have only left it here so others would know why this is bad. (multiple clients can access this same object and increment it, resulting in inconsistent results).

---

**Old answer**:

I figured it out.

The `Post` class looks like this:

```
class Post(Document):
      title = StringField(required=True)
      content = StringField(required=True)
      published_at = datetime.utcnow()
      ID = IntField(min_value=1)
```

And in the function that inserts the post, I count the available records and then increment them by 1, like so:

```
def create_post(title, content):
      Post(title=title, content=content, ID=Post.objects.count() + 1).save()
```

Comment: Mahmoud -that isn't the right solution, it contains a race condition and as such is liable to fail.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `mongoengine.signals` and the `post_init` for the sake of auto incrementing a field. haven't tested it btw.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

In my case I needed to create a sequential number for each invoice generated at the POS.

I used `class mongoengine.fields.SequenceField`

```
class Model(Document):
      .....
      sequenceSale = db.SequenceField(required=False) #(default int)
```

## NOTE

*in case the counter is defined in the abstract document, it will be common to all inherited documents and the default sequence name will be the class name of the abstract document.*

[More about mongoengine.fields.SequenceField](https://docs.mongoengine.org/apireference.html#mongoengine.fields.SequenceField)